# what does "inline operator T*() const" mean?

Tags: c++

I reviewed some codes on nullptr and found that:

```
const
class nullptr_t
{
public:
    template<class T>
    inline operator T*() const
        { return 0; }

    template<class C, class T>
    inline operator T C::*() const
        { return 0; }

private:
    void operator&() const;
} nullptr = {};
```

what do `inline operator T*() const` and `inline operator T C::*() const` mean?

Do they work the same way as `inline T operator *() const` or `inline T operator C::*() const`?

Why not specify the return type in the declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are user defined conversion operator functions.

A simpler function:

```
struct Foo
{
   inline operator int () const { return 0; }
};
```

Given that you can use

```
Foo f;
int i = f; // Invokes f.operator int () and initializes i with
           // return value.
```

For you class, which is an anonymous class for `nullptr`, what it means is that it can be converted to any pointer or member function pointer. You can use:

```
int* ip = nullptr;
```

It uses the return value of the first user defined conversion operator function to initialize `ip`.

```
struct Bar
{
   void bar() {}
};

void (Bar::*ptr)() = nullptr;
```

It uses the return value of the second user defined conversion operator function to initialize `ptr`.